# Running existing task with gulp-watch

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-watch

I've got some tasks already defined in `gulpfile.js` and I want to use `gulp-watch` plugin (to run tasks on new files). My question is, because I couldn't find anything, can I run my existing tasks while running watch (from plugin) function?

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    watch = require('gulp-watch'),
    ...;

gulp.task('lint', function () {
  return gulp.src(path.scripts)
      .pipe(jshint())
      .pipe(jshint.reporter(stylish));
});

gulp.task('watch', function () {
  watch({ glob: 'app/**/*.js' }); // Run 'lint' task for those files
});
```

Because I don't want to include `watch()` task in every task I have. I would like to have only 1 task - watch, which will combine all "watches".

----- EDIT ----
(as I probably didn't quite get my point):

I need to run task from inside of `gulp('watch')` task. for example:

like I did it with `gulp.watch`:

```
gulp.task('watch', function () {
  gulp.watch('files', ['task1', 'task2']);
});
```

I need to do the same but with `gulp-watch` plugin, something like (I know it wouldn't work):

```
var watch = require('gulp-watch');

gulp.task('watch', function () {
  watch({ glob: 'files' }, ['task1', 'task2']);
});
```

Answer (score 24):

I have also run into the problem of wanting to use gulp-watch (not gulp.watch), needing to use the callback form, and having trouble finding a suitable way to run a task in the callback.

My use case was that I wanted to watch all stylus files, but only process the main stylus file that includes all the others. Newer versions of gulp-watch may address this but I'm having problems with 4.3.x so I'm stuck on 4.2.5.

- gulp.run is deprecated so I don't want to use that.
- gulp.start works well, but is also advised against by the gulp author, contra.
- The run-sequence plugin works well and lets you define a run
  order, but it is a self-proclaimed hack:
  https://www.npmjs.com/package/run-sequence
- Contra suggest writing plain old functions and calling
  those. This is a new idea to me, but I think the example below captures the idea. https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/505

Take your pick.

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    watch = require('gulp-watch'), // not gulp.watch
    runSequence = require('run-sequence');

// plain old js function
var runStylus = function() {
    return gulp.src('index.styl')
        .pipe(...) // process single file
}

gulp.task('stylus', runStylus);

gulp.task('watch', function() {
    // watch many files
    watch('*.styl', function() {
        runSequence('stylus');
        OR 
        gulp.start('stylus');
        OR
        runStylus();
    });
});
```

All of these are working for me without warnings, but I'm still unsure about getting the "done" callback from the 4.2.x version of gulp-watch.

Comment: Wow, I've been running through gulp lately to get up to speed with some colleagues usage of it; your answer - although not accepted for this question - has answered about 4 other questions I had around `watch`, `run` & `run-sequence`, and to some degree usage of vanilla functions. So thanks for saving me a bunch of time :D

Answer (score 13):

You will most likely want to run specific tasks related to the files you are watching -

```
gulp.task('watch',['lint'], function () {
    gulp.watch('app/**/*.js' , ['lint']);
});
```

You can also use the `['lint']` portion to run any required tasks when watch first gets called, or utilize the tasks to run async with

```
gulp.task('default', ['lint','watch'])
```

Comment: Can you extend this to calling specific _tasks_ from within `gulp.watch` based on the _event type_.

Answer (score 7):

You can just call one task, that then includes both task

```
gulp.task('default', ['lint','watch'])
```

so here you would just call 'gulp'

Answer (score 4):

```
gulp.task('watch', function() {
  watch(files, function() {
    gulp.run(['task1', 'task2']);
  });
});
```

work fine, except a warning